# moving application with localdb to other machines

Tags: c#, connection-string

i've deployed my app,thath use a localdb sql based (.mdf)
i've built it and publish it.
on my pc works very well,but on other pc application don't read database.
i think is an issue on my connection string:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDb.mdf;
                  Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
```

application deployed on VS2013. i'm running win8,same as other pc i've try.

Comment: What's the error you get? It can't find the database? or it can't even connect to the server?

Comment: cant find database. but i need local database.

Comment: Then be sure to deploy the .mdf file too

Comment: mdf and ldf file i've deployed. i need to move all to other pc,but don't work

Answer (score 0):

You should try to connect to a db through the server and not locally, if you have SQL server attach the db there, and modify the connection string to connect to the db on the server, not on the local file.